# Inline PHP in a .JSP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsp

I am relatively new to web-development and am encountering an issue using some inline PHP code.

The page is a JavaServer Page (.jsp) and I am trying to implement a [JFormer](http://www.jformer.com/) form.

When I add my JFormer PHP code to my .jsp page, it just displays as plain-text and refuses to cooperate with me (even when using demo code from the site's documentation). Is this because of some sort of incompatibility between using PHP on a .jsp page?

If that is the case, what are some work-around that I could use? Should I use an iframe?

I need to preserve the use of the .jsp page and would prefer very much to use JFormer, but if I have to I can toss it.

Example of something similar to what I am doing can be found at: http://www.jformer.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/

Comment: What does this have to do with JSP?  jFormer is just JavaScript and CSS...

Comment: It has to do with JSP because I am/was trying to implement it onto a .jsp page. Like I said, I am very new to web-development so apologies for any confusion.

Comment: ... unless you HAVE to mix php and jsp, I'd vote to avoid it if at all possible. Have you tried looking for an equivalent solution that jsp based?

Comment: I do not have to use JFormer, I just liked the feel of it. I will look for an alternative as I was unaware how potentially troublesome this would be.

Comment: @ssell - see my answer below.  Don't try to do both PHP and JSP in a single project.  ESPECIALLY since you're just learning how it all works.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses everyone. My knowledge of web-development is very limited and was unaware of these limitations/potential complications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSP and PHP are both server-side languages. As such, all scripting in a given file must be processed by the required engines on the server to produce the necessary HTML output.

I suppose it is possible to rig multiple engines inline to process first JSP, then PHP, but that seems cumbersome and error prone.

Instead, consider using an iframe (as you suggested) or load the PHP content via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is executed by a PHP interpreter and output HTML. JSP is compiled and executed by a Java VM, and output HTML. You can't execute PHP inside JSP code (and vice-versa). It's like if you put Chinese words inside an English speech. Nobody can understand.

Comment: Thanks for the clear analogy. I was recently assigned to this project with no prior experience in web-development (just years of graphics programming. Odd, I know.) so was unaware of this.

Answer (score 3):

I think the point of this is that the examples for jFormer use PHP for the server side logic.  If you want to integrate jFormer into your JSP project, **learn how to code the equivalent PHP functionality in JSP**.  You may need to create a Servlet for portions of the logic.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like JFormer requires PHP so you can't make this work on a JSP page easily. You can rewrite the JFormer PHP code in Java/JSP but this may be a lot of work.

The container (like Tomcat) you're using may be able to run PHP scripts as CGI scripts. If you do this you can't easily share session information between PHP and Java. Javascript could be used to accomplish this, but beware of security issues. If you still want to use JSP you could make an iframe that points to the PHP page, as you said.

Here's an article on setting that up for Tomcat:
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp

Disclaimer: I don't know JFormer.